# Filter multiple ajax tables with one filter on Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-filter, django-tables2

Hello and Thank you for your time, I recently started using django and need some help.
I have multiple ajax-tables rendered in an html template as in the documentation:

https://pypi.org/project/django-ajax-tables/

I have a table per view and render them in different divs of the same html page.

All the models for this tables have a foreing_key of a model called Location, and all this child models have a date.

I want a filter for this tables where I can enter Location and start_date and on submit(or on type|select) all tables get updated.  What would be the best way to do this on Django?

Comment: Looks like you'd want to use the Javascript API https://github.com/KiwiTrinsic/django-ajax-tables#javascript-api to trigger the other tables to update.

Comment: Ok, did that, working. Multiple tables get loaded, page does not reload, lazy paginator.  What about the query input, I can see it is being filtered and if it is not valid it gets rejected.  Is this always secure, like using forms and csrf token?